# How to controll an ImageView with an Audio Player seekbar?

Tags: java, android, audio, slideshow, seekbar

I'am using this player as a base for the project:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

I addition to that when I wanted to show different Images (kind of a slideshow) while playing the Audiofile. 
Each image has a starttime and duration value.

I've archieved to play this slideshow of images, but with the problem, that I can't stop or pause it.

My Goal is an ImageView where I can controll the shown Image over the seekbar and the Play and Pause function, so that every Image will be shown at the right time while scrolling through the seekbar. (Same like the Audio file gets controlled kind of)

Right know I'm kind of stuck and need some approach to continue my work.
Anybody an idea how to solve this?